# GCP Console script to automatically migrate VPS to higher tier?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is there a sample `gccloud` script to migrate a machine from `general-purpose` to `compute-optimised` ? Its a webserver so I'd rather the new machine keeps the IP also. Downtime 10-20 min is OK.

Comment: Resizing Compute Engine instances is well documented. Please update your question with a problem that you are experiencing that is not covered by the documentation. I am voting to close this question and downvoting for showing no reasonable effort in solving your task before posting this question.

Comment: infinite knowledge can be gained with infinite amount of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing VM type in `gcloud` requires setting default region and zone for the project, stopping VM, changing type:

```
# set defaults
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata \
  --metadata google-compute-default-region=us-east4,google-compute-default-zone=us-east4-c

# check it was set (see commonInstanceMetadata section)
gcloud compute project-info describe --project YOURPROJECTNAME

# reinit gcloud to enable new defaults
gcloud init

# change machine type
gcloud compute instances stop VMNAME

gcloud compute instances set-machine-type VMNAME --machine-type e2-highcpu-4

gcloud compute instances start VMNAME
```

*Note: you need static IP to be 100% sure IP wont change afterwards*